# Como colocar botões/títulos com diferente design/estilo no C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

No C# há alguma maneira de meter por exemplo os botões com um diferente design, ou o título com um diferente estilo? Eu quero meter o meu programa mais "fancy".

Comment: sugestões de ferramentas gera respostas principalmente baseada em opiniões, acredito que não caiba esse tipo de pergunta aqui pois fica quase impossível decidir qual é a resposta correta.

Comment: @Math Acho válida esse tipo de pergunta. As respostas geralmente são apresentações de editores atuais mais preferidos pela comunidade. Esse tipo de informação é amplamente solicitada. Mas como você bem citou, fica quase impossível decidir qual é a resposta correta.

Comment: @Ricardo concordo que o material pode ter algum valor, principalmente enquanto as respostas são novas, mas novamente: é quase impossível determinar qual é a resposta correta dentre uma lista de sugestões; além do mais, com o passar do tempo as respostas ficarão desatualizadas, quem irá atualizar as respostas? Ninguém. Esse tipo de questão cabe mais em um fórum do que aqui, que é um site de perguntas e respostas. Veja uma discussão interessante [nesse link](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/819/3117)

Comment: acredito que um bom lugar para por esse tipo de informações é aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info Quem possuir reputação o suficiente pode editar a wiki tag e sugerir ferramentas, livros e etc.

Comment: @Math Realmente, concordo com você.

Comment: @math editei a pergunta do Katomara, perguntando especificamente sobre como colocar botões ou títulos com diferentes design no C#. Acho que dessa forma o escopo fica claro, e não meramente uma pergunta de sugestão.

Comment: Concordo com você @Math. Mas, se o autor da pergunta alterá-la para ser mais na linha "é possível customizar a aparência/estilo de botões no C#?" sem solicitar ferramentas, talvez a pergunta se torne mais interessante e válida no escopo. :)

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, concordo, acabei de editar a pergunta.

Comment: @carloscinelli Eu vi sua edição, bacana. P.S.: Pessoalmente eu acho mais correto nesses casos deixar o autor editar, porque ele pode não concordar ou ter um entendimento diferente do meu/seu. Por isso sugeri a edição ao invés de fazê-la. Mas, enfim, acho que a sua edição deve ajudar a pergunta. :)

Comment: @carloscinelli Editei mais um pouco e votei para reabrir.

Comment: Eu votei pela reabertura. Enquanto que a pergunta é open-ended, a escolha de tecnologias limita a gama de soluções possíveis.

Comment: @bfavaretto bacana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está buscando pelo [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a solução da Microsoft para aplicações ricas. Mas tenha em mente que há uma curva de aprendizado acentuada para desenvolvedores *WinForms*. Se você tem alguma experiência com desenvolvimento de aplicações ricas (*Flex*, *JavaFX* ou principalmente *Silverlight*) e um bom entendimento de linguagens de *markup* modernas os princípios do WPF são mais naturais. Comece pesquisando sobre [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms747122%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=vrNnhYS43Mn), uma linguagem baseada em XML, contra-metade do C# (ou qualquer outra linguagem da plataforma .NET) usada na declaração de componentes.

Answer (score 4):

Para os botões ou títulos com diferentes designs você poderia simplesmente usar uma PictureBox e colocar uma imagem específica. Agora, se desejar algo um pouco mais complexo, você pode criar uma classe herdando a classe Button (no caso de ser um botão) e mudar alguns detalhes, sobrescrever eventos usando *override* de acordo com seu critério etc.

A nível de curiosidade, segue o código de como criar um botão personalizado usando a classe [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BotaoPersonalizado objBotao = new BotaoPersonalizado(); //Inicializando o botão personalizado.

        //Incluindo a ele um evento Click:
        EventHandler evento = new EventHandler(objBotao_Click);
        objBotao.Click += evento;

        objBotao.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 200); //Definindo sua posição na tela.
        objBotao.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 305); //Definindo seu tamanho.

        this.Controls.Add(objBotao); //Adicionando o controle ao formulário.
    }

    public class BotaoPersonalizado : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {
        //Sobrescrevendo o método OnPaint para desenhar o botão:
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);

            float cordenadaX = 0, cordenadaY = 0, largura = 100, altura = 100; //Definindo características da elipse delimitada por um retângulo.
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, cordenadaX, cordenadaY, largura, altura); //Desenhando a elipse.
            pen.Dispose(); //Liberando os recursos usados.
        }
    }

    void objBotao_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Olá");
    }
```